# Problems with object reflection in nested form with has_many association

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, coffeescript

I'm trying to implement the `has_many` pattern shown in "[Ruby on Rails Nested Attributes](http://tutorials.pluralsight.com/ruby-ruby-on-rails/ruby-on-rails-nested-attributes)".  I'm combining it with some of my own methods and know exactly where it's raising an exception and why.  I just don't know how to fix it.  I'm using `accepts_nested_attributes`.  I have a class called `ProfilePhones`.

In profile_email.rb:

```
def self.attrs
  column_names.map(&:to_sym) - [:created_at, :updated_at]
end
```

The use the above for nested attributes so if the model changes it doesn't break the other controller.  In the profiles_controller.rb I have:

```
def profile_params
  params.require(:profile).permit(.... profile_phones_attributes: ProfilePhone.attrs)
```

In the Profile views folder, I have _profile_email_fields.html.erb with the fields for the ProfilePhone records:

```
<%= f.text_field :kind, placeholder: "Type" %>
<%= f.text_field :email_address, placeholder: "Email" %>
```

There's a bit more in this partial, but I'm simplifying it because the partial functions fine.  In the main _form partial I have the following:

```
<%= f.fields_for :profile_emails do |f| %>
  <%= render 'profile_email_fields', f: f %>
  <%= link_to_add_fields('Add Another Email', f, :profile_emails) %>
<% end %>
```

In application_helper.rb:

```
 def link_to_add_fields(name = nil, f = nil, association = nil, options = nil, html_options = nil, &block)
   f, association, options, html_options = name, f, association, options if block_given?

   options = {} if options.nil?
   html_options = {} if html_options.nil?

   if options.include? :locals
     locals = options[:locals]
   else
     locals = { }
   end

   if options.include? :partial
     partial = options[:partial]
   else
     partial = association.to_s.singularize + '_fields'
   end

   new_object = f.object.class.reflect_on_association(association).klass.new
   fields = f.fields_for(association, new_object, child_index: 'new_record') do |builder|
     render(partial, locals.merge!( f: builder))
   end

   html_options['data-form-prepend'] = raw CGI::escapeHTML( fields )
   html_options['href'] = '#'

   content_tag(:a, name, html_options, &block)
end
```

Finally, in the profiles.coffee:

```
$('[data-form-prepend]').click (e) ->
  obj = $($(this).attr('data-form-prepend'))
  obj.find('input, select, textarea').each ->
    $(this).attr 'name', ->
      $(this).attr('name').replace 'new_record', (new Date).getTime()
    return
  obj.insertBefore this
  false
```

The problem is in the `application_helper` method above on the following line:

```
 new_object = f.object.class.reflect_on_association(association).klass.new
```

f.object.class returns:

```
ProfileEmail(id: integer, kind: string, email_address: string, profile_id: integer, created_at: datetime, updated_at: datetime)
```

association is set as `:profile_emails`.  The problem is that this produces Nil.  Also, I need to reflect on the model it belongs to Profile.  When I switch out with:

```
Profile.reflect_on_association(association).klass.new
```

It returns:

```
->  #<ProfileEmail id: nil, kind: nil, email_address: nil, profile_id: nil, created_at: nil, updated_at: nil>
```

Which is what I want.  However, when I go to the view and click on 'Add another email' link   nothing happens.  This probably an issue either with my coffeescript or a consequence of calling Profile explicitly.  I'm not sure.

My two problems are:

1. In my reflection method I should be reflecting on Profile and not Profile email, but I'm not sure how to fix it.  I can get a string of the profile name, but that doesn't help.
2. When I explicitly call Profile in the helper method, nothing happens.

Answer (score 0):

one problem seems to be that you have shadowing variable names for the form_builder parameter here:

```
<%= f.fields_for :profile_emails do |f| %>
  <%= render 'profile_email_fields', f: f %>
  <%= link_to_add_fields('Add Another Email', f, :profile_emails) %>
<% end %>
```

try changing to

```
<%= f.fields_for :profile_emails do |ff| %>
  <%= render 'profile_email_fields', f: ff %>
  <%= link_to_add_fields('Add Another Email', f, :profile_emails) %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: Thank you so much.  Sometimes the issues is just staring you in the face.